# Getting java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification exception while using iterators?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, iterator

I am using the `listIterator()` for accessing and removing items from a `LinkedList` in a class that implements`Runnable` I am also modifying values of this list in some other part of the program concurrently.

Where I am using `listIterator()` in this part of the code I am getting `ConcurrentModificationException` from this function call:

**java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification**

Why do I get this and how do I prevent it?

```
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        while(true)
        {
            itr = nodeAttributes.listIterator();

            while (itr.hasNext()) 
            {
                System.out.println("enterred");
                nodeAttribute nA = (nodeAttribute) itr.next();
                //System.out.println("for");
                 if(!nA.isMoving && !nA.moveQueue.isEmpty())
                 {
                     if(animator != null)
                         animator.stop();

                     animator = (Animator) nA.moveQueue.poll();
                     //itr.remove();
                     animator.start();
                     nA.isMoving = true;
                     System.out.print( "animator");
                 }
            }
            System.out.println( "looping");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have something like a stack trace so you know in which line it appears?

Comment: No I don't know on which line it happens.

Comment: Did you try using a try catch around the content of your inner for loop yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post doesn't have a question, just a statement. However what you describe is the expected behaviour. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the Iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

So to prevent this you need to prevent modification by a writer at the same time as a reader is iterating. Use the [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) method. All access (readers and writers) should follow this pattern:

```
// store a single synchronized list reference for all access to use
nodeAttributes = Collections.synchronizedList(theLinkedList);
```

and then all readers and writers should use a `synchronized (list)` block.

```
// Readers might do:
synchronized (list) {
  itr = nodeAttributes.listIterator();
  while (i.hasNext())
      ... do stuff ...
}
```

Those threads that operate without iterating can just use the "atomic" methods on the return object from `Collections.synchronizedList`, such as `add`. These methods use a sync block under the covers, so they are just a shorthand and they will still block the thread while another is in a sync block.

There are many, many ways to deal with concurrent reader and writers.

1. One is the above, but it may lock out other threads for a long time while each iterator does it's stuff.
2. Another is to copy the list to an array (inside a synchronized section) and then read the array outside the lock.
3. Yet another would be to use a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

and there are more options, all dependent on your exact use case.

Comment: After putting the inner loop in a `try-catch` statement no longer exception occurs . I am confused why the code acts strangely? or is it a matter of chance that no longer exceptions occur?

Comment: @AliNfr yes, that was probably chance. You are breaking the golden rule: do not read and write to an unsynchronized list in two threads at the same time.

Comment: What happens if I just ignore the exception by catching it? It seems nothing bad is happening.

Comment: @AliNfr bad things may happen and you will just have hidden the consequences of them: your read iterators won't finish iterating the entire list, for one. There is only one valid solution: synchronize your list access for all threads.

Comment: Should I change the other part of the code that is modifying and reading the list (by the same way for this part)? , Because I am still getting exceptions.

Comment: As per my post "*All access should follow this pattern*". That means readers *and* writers. It is worth you reading the java tutorials section [on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), and in particular on concurrent lists.

Comment: If I just want to add to the list by `itr.add()` method and not iterating the list should I use the synchronized block again?